# Настроить редирект в .htaccess (убрать /index.php/ из url)

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Есть url:

```
http://site.ru/index.php/content
```

Помогите убрать /index.php/ из ссылки, чтобы она выглядела так:

```
http://site.ru/content
```

---

У меня уже есть решение этой проблемы:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Проблема в том, что на сайте настроен редирект на без «/». И когда я использую это решение, редирект на без «/» перестаёт работать.

**Как убрать** /index.php/ **из ссылки и сохранить при этом редирект на без «/»?**

С уважением, Олег.